# TSQL - SQL Server fill Value with Value of previous filled date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to da a tricky thing in my fact table.
My customer wants to fill every empty value in the fact table with the value of the previous filled date.

[image: Fill Values with previous dates]

It gets complicated, when I need to consinder, that it should only update the Values, if the context of the dimensions is the same.

This is the expected result:

[image: expected Result]

We're Using Microsoft Analysis Services so maybe this can also be done with MDX and LastNonEmpty, but for now it would be finde to have a working update Statement for the fact table. (Fact table with 0 values is generated by using the actual fact table cross joining all possible day combinations).

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `apply`:

```
select t.dim1, t.dim2, t.dimdate, t2.value
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.dim1 = t.dim1 and t2.dim2 = t.dim2 and
            t2.dimdate <= t.dimdate and t2.value <> 0
      order by t2.dimdate desc
     ) t2;
```

SQL does offer functionality to do what you want using window functions.  It is the `IGNORE NULLS` option on `LAG()`.  Unfortunately, SQL Server does not implement this option.

You can do this with window functions, but it is a bit more cumbersome:

```
select t.dim1, t.dim2, t.dimdate,
       max(value) over (partition by dim1, dim2, effectivedimdate) as value
from (select t.*,
             (case when value = 0
                   then max(case when value <> 0 then dimdate end) over (partition by dim1, dim2 order by dimdate)
                   else dimdate
              end) as effective_dimdate
      from t
     ) t;
```

The `max()` scan gets the most recent `dimdate` that has a non-zero value.  The value is then "spread" over all the values using another `max()` scan.

Note:  This assumes that the value that you want to apply is always greater than zero.  The code is easily  modified to handle this, but the additional `case` expression just complicates the logic.

Either of these can easily be turned into an update.  The second is particularly easy:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(value) over (partition by dim1, dim2, effectivedimdate) as new_value
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when value = 0
                         then max(case when value <> 0 then dimdate end) over (partition by dim1, dim2 order by dimdate)
                         else dimdate
                    end) as effective_dimdate
            from t
           ) t
     )
update toupdate
    set value = newvalue
    where value = 0;
```